# A Framework of subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I have a subclass of `UIView` lets call `MainView`. I create many subclasses of `MainView`, which I call "components". What I need is for other developers to be able to create their own components (with assets) so i can link them to the project. Similar to the effect of plugins. For copyright reasons the source code needs to be hidden, so I believe a framework is the best method, but i have some issues with this.

All the new components in this framework will need to be a subclass of `MainView`. Will I have to create a different 'framework X' that contains `MainView` and link it to both the 'new components framework' and the main project? This is not ideal as the main project is huge and 'framework X' will need a lot more classes than just `MainView` and it could get messy. Or is there a simpler way to do this?

I have never created a framework before and my needs are not what frameworks are designed to do, so I am unclear on the best way to go about this and could use some advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a static library (.a) and the public headers... which is sort of what a mac `Framework` is (that uses a dynamic library, but it is a library with headers.) ...

MainView.h

```
@interface MainView : UIView
-(void) someMethods;
@property int someProperty;
@end
```

then just supply them with a compiled version of MainView.o probably packaged as yourlib.a
and that header...

They will just implement their interface like:

```
#import "MainView.h"

@interface SomeTypeOfView : MainView
@end
```

Comment: This sounds good to me, I will implement it then come back to accept your answer. Very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @FusionReactor actually you probably just want to use the subclass, the protocol would probably just be confusing and harder to implement... I am going to just clarify...

Comment: I did as Grady suggested and it worked perfectly. Thanks